# Update query for all services per customer except most recent

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

Overall what I'm trying to do is only display the most recent customer records who have **not** shown up for service in the **previous 30 days** & ONLY display the most recent service record according to current date.

There are two tables & they are structured in a one to many relationship.

The first table is table: "customer"

```
|---------------------------------------------------|
| ID | FirstName | LastName | Male | Female | Phone | 
|---------------------------------------------------|
  35    John       Mulling    True    False    905    
  84    Mike       Stone      True    False    416    
  90    Cassie     Daniels    False   True     315
```

The second table is table: "tblservice"

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| ServiceID  |  Followup30 | Timing     | Service1 | Total   | customerID |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
      1         Yes         01/02/2012   Serv-001   120.00       35
      2         No          02/05/2012   Serv-003   500.00       84
      3         No          03/25/2012   Serv-008    85.00       90
```

This list is filtered in the user interface via the following query which is checked either once a week or once a month by an employee to follow up with the customer (once call is made to customer, employee sets 'followup30' checkbox to 'Yes'):

```
SELECT customer.FirstName, customer.LastName, customer.Male, customer.Female,
customer.Phone, tblservice.Followup30, tblservice.Timing, tblservice.Service1,
tblservice.Total 
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN tblservice 
ON customer.ID=tblservice.customerID 
WHERE (((tblservice.Followup30)=No) 
AND ((tblservice.Timing)<=DateAdd("d",-30,Date())) 
AND ((customer.Phone) Is Not Null)) 
ORDER BY tblservice.Timing;
```

However the problem seems to be when a customer comes in say within 20 days, his/her previous entry is still in the system which needs following up. 
(I do **not** want to show this old service record only the most recent & IF it's more than 30 days old)

The above query in the UI will take care of the 30 days or older part but however I need to cleanse the system of old customer service entries in the list.

**The Attempt:**

So I want to execute a update query upon loading the user interface which will cleanse this list of all old service entries for the employee.

I just want the query to set all entries for a true/false field(followup30) in the services table for each customer to true **except** for the most recently dated one.

This is what I have so far but I don't think it treats each customer separatly and there may be a few syntax issues.

```
UPDATE tblservice
SET followup30='Yes'
WHERE (SELECT Timing FROM tblservice WHERE Timing <> (SELECT MAX(Timing) 
FROM tblservice));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE tblservice
    SET followup30 = 'Yes'
    FROM (select max(Timing) as maxTiming
          from tblservice ts
          where tblservice.CustomerId = ts.Customerid
         ) t
    where tblservice.Timing = maxTiming
```

I think this captures the logic that you want, of only looking at the most recent record.  (You might need to modify it to put in the 30-day logic.)

Comment: I have tried the following query but seem to be running into a syntax error as follows:
"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression "Yes' FROM (select max(Timing) as maxTiming from tblservice ts where tblservice.CustomerId = ts.Customerid)'

Comment: Alas, I was wondering if Access allowed this syntax.  I added a table alias in the FROM clause (which should have been there originally).  However, I'm guessing that the FROM clause itself might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can do this with embedded SQL however if you create a query called LastService as follows

```
SELECT tblService.CustomerId, Max(tblService.Timeing) AS MaxOfTimeing FROM tblService GROUP BY tblService.CustomerId;
```

then you can use it in an update query as follows

```
UPDATE customer INNER JOIN LastService ON customer.CustomerId = LastService.CustomerId SET customer.Followup30 = iif(LastService.MaxOfTimeing<DateAdd("d",-30,Now()),'YES','NO')
```

This is assuming Followup30 is a text field, if it is a YES/NO field you will have to adjust the update query accordingly.

Comment: Hey Chris thanks for your response, I went ahead and created both queries and updated the second by removing the 'NO' also needed to change "Timeing" to Timing". It seems i am getting an error "Enter Parameter Value for Customer.Customerid".  I then go ahead just to get the query to do it's thing and enter in a customerid I know has two services and get another error "operation must use an updatable query".  FYI I am using ms access if it makes a difference.